# just starting and cant find a place to learn a launguage to code games

Tags: software-engineering

Like i said im justing starting and it feals like it is impossible to learn a launguage. Id like to code games and would appreciate it if some one could direct me to a site where I could learn how to do so.

Comment: "How do I get started?" questions are off topic here as described in the [FAQ]. Try googling it though!

Comment: Additionally, if you read the [FAQ] it will direct you to some sites for getting started.

Answer (score 1):

It is no easy task to program a game, you need to have a solid background in mathematics especially linear algebra if you want to program 3D games.

If you have no interest in maths, algorithms and serious programming, but just want to create games then look at this http://mashable.com/2008/01/04/20-tools-for-creating-your-own-games/

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a book about programming in a language you think seems interesting. For an example a Java book. You can't write a game before you know how to write code. There are tons of programming books on Amazon, which hopefully will give you inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this is the wrong place ask that question. But here's a link anyway: [Lazy Foo Tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php). The tutorials are designed from ground up to teach game development in C++ using the SDL library. If that's too much for you, consider taking an introductory programming course on [Udacity](http://www.udacity.com/) or [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/).